# How can I convert TBytes to RawByteString?

Tags: delphi, string, delphi-2009

What is the best way to convert an array of bytes declared as TBytes to a RawByteString in Delphi 2009? This code actually works, maybe there is a faster way (without loop):

```
   function Convert(Bytes: TBytes): RawByteString; 
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     SetLength(Result, Length(Bytes));
     for I := 0 to ABytes - 1 do
       Result[I + 1] := AnsiChar(Bytes[I]);
   end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to convert bytes to a `RawByteString` is to use `SetString()`.

Also, to avoid data loss if the `RawByteString` is ever assigned to other String types, you should assign a codepage to the `RawByteString` so that its character data gets converted correctly to the charset of the receiving String:

```
function Convert(const Bytes: TBytes): RawByteString; 
begin
  SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(PByte(Bytes))^, Length(Bytes));
  SetCodePage(Result, ..., False);
end;
```

Comment: I thought the point of using `RawByteString` is that it lacks codepage information in contrast to types like `AnsiString` or `Utf8String`.

Comment: @blerontin `RawByteString` lacks a charset at *compile time*, but it inherits the *runtime* charset of whatever string is assigned to it. And a byte array has an implied charset to it, even if one is not carried in the byte payload itself. Like I said in my answer, `RawByteString` can be assigned to other string types, so it needs to carry a valid charset in its payload to facilitate proper assignments to avoid data loss

Answer (score 17):

The best way is this:

```
function Convert(const Bytes: TBytes): RawByteString; inline;
begin
  SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(pointer(Bytes)), length(Bytes));
end;
```

And don't forget to use const for Bytes parameters, for somewhat faster generated code.

Answer (score 7):

You could consider using move (untested)

```
function Convert(const Bytes: TBytes): RawByteString; 
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Bytes));
  Move(Bytes[0], Result[1], Length(Bytes))  
end;
```

And use "const" for the parameter so the array is not copied twice.

Comment: `SetLength()` will call `ReallocMem` to resize the existing RawByteString, so this version would perhaps unnecessary `move()` the previous data, without need, e.g. if you call this in a loop. `SetString(Result,PAnsiChar(Bytes),length(Bytes)` will be faster.

Answer (score 5):

And remember to test:

IF Length(Bytes)>0 THEN MOVE.....

Comment: This should be a comment on the first (accepted) answer, I guess.