# Why does the usage of TStringStream.DataString fail when TStringStream loads binary non-textual file?

Tags: string, delphi, hex, delphi-xe, stringstream

1. As the experts have been kindly suggested, `TStringStream.DataString` cannot be used to retrieve `non-text` data loaded by `TStringStream.LoadFromFile`, because `TStringStream.GetDataString` will call `TEncoding`'s encoding methods, which, take `TMBCSEncoding` for example, will call `TMBCSEncoding.GetChars` which in turn calls `TMBCSEncoding.UnicodeFromLocaleChars` and finally `Windows`'s `MultiByteToWideChar`.
2. TBytes is recommended to be used as data buffer/binary storage. (For this purpose, TBytes is recommended over AnsiString.)
3. The `bytes` can be retrieved from `TStringStream.ReadBuffer` method or `TStringStream.Bytes` property. Either way, `TStream.Size` should be considered.

====================================================

I am trying to use `TStringStream` and its `DataString` for base64-encoding/decoding purposes. It seems possible as indicated by `Nils Haeck`'s reply [here](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/3/321962.html) or [here](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.graphics/200712/0712125679.html).

1. Using `TStringStream.DataString` in `TMainForm.QuestionOfString_StringStream` (No.2 to No.7) fail in that the information is corrupted (i.e., not the same as the original information). However, `ss_loaded_2.SaveToFile` (No.1) saves the original information, indicating `TStringStream` does hold decoded non-textual data correctly internally? Could you help to comment about the possible reasons of DataString corruption?
2. In `Rob Kennedy`'s kind answer, he mentioned `string` or `ansistring` should be avoid in storing base64-decoded non-textual data, which makes great sense. However, as shown in `TMainForm.QuestionOfString_NativeXML`, the `DecString` of `AnsiString`type contains the decoded bytes so correctly that the data can be encoded back. Does this mean AnsiString can hold decoded non-texual data intact?
3. `David Heffernan` and `Rob Kennedy` have kindly commented about bytes/TBytes. However, `bytes` extracted in `TMainForm.QuestionOfString_NativeXML_Bytes_1` , is different from `TStringStream`'s `Bytes` in `TMainForm.QuestionOfString_NativeXML_Bytes_2`. (From Base64-encoding/decoding results, the `TStringStream.Bytes` is wrong. It is confusing because based on the above paragraph, `TStringStream` should contain the intact bytes internally?) Could you help to comment about the possible reason?

Thank you very much for your help!

PS: The sample files can be download from SkyDrive: [REF_EncodedSample & REF_DecodedSample](http://sdrv.ms/LzLxlZ). (Zlib-compressed image file.).

PS: Delphi XE, Windows 7. (It seems TStringStream back in Delphi 7 doesn't have LoadFromFile or SaveToFile.)

#### sample code

```
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  CodeSiteLogging,
  NativeXml, // v3.10
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure QuestionOfString_StringStream;
    procedure QuestionOfString_NativeXML;
    procedure QuestionOfString_NativeXML_Bytes_1;
    procedure QuestionOfString_NativeXML_Bytes_2;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}    

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773297/how-can-i-convert-tbytes-to-rawbytestring
function Convert(const Bytes: TBytes): RawByteString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Bytes));
  if Length(Bytes) > 0 then
  begin
    Move(Bytes[0], Result[1], Length(Bytes));
    // SetCodePage(Result, CP_ACP, False);
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  QuestionOfString_StringStream;
  QuestionOfString_NativeXML;
  QuestionOfString_NativeXML_Bytes_1;
  QuestionOfString_NativeXML_Bytes_2;
end;

// http://www.delphigroups.info/2/3/321962.html
// http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.graphics/200712/0712125679.html
procedure TMainForm.QuestionOfString_StringStream;
var
  ss_loaded_2, ss_loaded_3: TStringStream;
  dataStr: AnsiString;
  hexOfDataStr: AnsiString;
begin
  ss_loaded_2 := TStringStream.Create();
  // load the file containing Base64-decoded sample data
  ss_loaded_2.LoadFromFile('REF_DecodedSample');

  // 1  
  ss_loaded_2.SaveToFile('REF_DecodedSample_1_SavedByStringStream');

  // 2 
  ss_loaded_3 := TStringStream.Create(ss_loaded_2.DataString);
  ss_loaded_3.SaveToFile('REF_DecodedSample_2_SavedByStringStream');

  // 3     
  ss_loaded_3.Free;
  ss_loaded_3 := TStringStream.Create(ss_loaded_2.DataString, TEncoding.ASCII);
  ss_loaded_3.SaveToFile('REF_DecodedSample_3_SavedByStringStream');

  // 4     
  ss_loaded_3.Free;
  ss_loaded_3 := TStringStream.Create(ss_loaded_2.DataString, TEncoding.UTF8);
  ss_loaded_3.SaveToFile('REF_DecodedSample_4_SavedByStringStream');

  // 5     
  ss_loaded_3.Free;
  ss_loaded_3 := TStringStream.Create(AnsiString(ss_loaded_2.DataString));
  ss_loaded_3.SaveToFile('REF_DecodedSample_5_SavedByStringStream');

  // 6     
  ss_loaded_3.Free;
  ss_loaded_3 := TStringStream.Create(UTF8String(ss_loaded_2.DataString));
  ss_loaded_3.SaveToFile('REF_DecodedSample_6_SavedByStringStream');

  // 7 
  dataStr := ss_loaded_2.DataString;
  SetLength(hexOfDataStr, 2 * Length(dataStr));
  BinToHex(@dataStr[1], PAnsiChar(@hexOfDataStr[1]), Length(dataStr));
  CodeSite.Send(hexOfDataStr);

  ss_loaded_2.Free;
  ss_loaded_3.Free;
end;

// http://www.simdesign.nl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1311
procedure TMainForm.QuestionOfString_NativeXML;
var
  LEnc, LDec: integer;
  EncStream: TMemoryStream;
  DecStream: TMemoryStream;
  EncString: AnsiString;
  DecString: AnsiString;
begin
  // encode and decode streams
  EncStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  DecStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // load BASE64-encoded data
    EncStream.LoadFromFile('REF_EncodedSample');
    LEnc := EncStream.Size;
    SetLength(EncString, LEnc);
    EncStream.Read(EncString[1], LEnc);

    // decode BASE64-encoded data, after removing control chars
    DecString := DecodeBase64(sdRemoveControlChars(EncString));
    LDec := length(DecString);
    DecStream.Write(DecString[1], LDec);

    // save the decoded data
    DecStream.SaveToFile('REF_DecodedSample_7_SavedByNativeXml');

    // EncString := sdAddControlChars(EncodeBase64(DecString), #$0D#$0A);
    EncString := EncodeBase64(DecString);

    // clear and resave encode stream as a copy
    EncStream.Clear;
    EncStream.Write(EncString[1], Length(EncString));
    EncStream.SaveToFile('REF_EncodedSampleCopy');

  finally
    EncStream.Free;
    DecStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.QuestionOfString_NativeXML_Bytes_1;
var
  LEnc, LDec: integer;
  EncStream: TMemoryStream;
  DecStream: TMemoryStream;
  EncString: AnsiString;
  DecString: AnsiString;
  DecBytes: TBytes;
begin
  // encode and decode streams
  EncStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  DecStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // load BASE64-decoded data
    DecStream.LoadFromFile('REF_DecodedSample');

    LDec := DecStream.Size;
    SetLength(DecBytes, LDec);
    DecStream.Read(DecBytes[0], LDec);

    EncString := EncodeBase64(Convert(DecBytes));

    // clear and resave encode stream as a copy
    EncStream.Write(EncString[1], Length(EncString));
    EncStream.SaveToFile('REF_EncodedSampleCopy_Bytes_1');

  finally
    EncStream.Free;
    DecStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.QuestionOfString_NativeXML_Bytes_2;
var
  LEnc, LDec: integer;
  EncStream: TMemoryStream;
  DecStream: TStringStream;
  EncString: AnsiString;
  DecString: AnsiString;
  DecBytes: TBytes;
begin
  // encode and decode streams
  EncStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  DecStream := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    // load BASE64-decoded data
    DecStream.LoadFromFile('REF_DecodedSample');

    DecBytes := DecStream.Bytes;

    EncString := EncodeBase64(Convert(DecBytes));

    // clear and resave encode stream as a copy
    EncStream.Write(EncString[1], Length(EncString));
    EncStream.SaveToFile('REF_EncodedSampleCopy_Bytes_2');

  finally
    EncStream.Free;
    DecStream.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Repeatedly creating the same object without freeing looks problematic.  What if you created each object just once and replaced the datastring and encoding as needed?

Comment: Not freeing objects IS problematic. Not sure if it's the source of your specific problem though.

Comment: Byte order? What is the difference in the strings

Comment: Dear Argalatyr and Jerry Dodge, Thank you for your comments! I made the corrections as you suggest.

Comment: Dear Despatcher, the values are not the same.

Comment: @Xichen - Your question seems to be continuously evolving. At the point you get your answer for your original question, consider asking another question.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: Thank you for your alert! I am just trying not to ask related questions which could be warned and closed as duplicates. (Nonetheless, I will remember not to modify the original post too much to hurt the answers.)

Comment: @Sertac, the question is ultimately still asking why `TStringStream` fails. It's just requiring a deeper investigation. The surface answer is that code pages interfere, but where, exactly, does that happen, since the mere act of loading and saving the data doesn't do it. I surmised that `TStringStream` might keep its data in the same `TBytes` storage that its ancestor `TBytesStream` uses, but the latest update suggests I'm wrong since the `Bytes` property doesn't match the directly loaded data.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Thank you for your time and kind help! (I just posted another question about TStringStream.Bytes ... :D)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really no surprise that examples 3 through 7 fail. Your file is not textual data, so storing it in a text data structure is bound to show problems. Each of those tests involves converting the data from one encoding to another. Since your data isn't encoded as UTF-16 text to begin with, any conversion that expects the data to have that encoding is going to fail.

Example 2 probably fails because you have an odd number of bytes, and you're storing it in a string that by definition contains an even number of bytes. Somewhere, a byte is going to be introduced or dropped, causing different data to be stored.

Unless you're dealing with text, don't use `TStringStream`, `string`, or `AnsiString`. Try `TBytesStream` or `TMemoryStream` instead.

Feel free to store Base64-encoded data in a string. Base64 is a text format. But once you decode it, it's binary again, and has no business being in a text data structure anymore.

The reason you see different results now from what Nils Haeck suggested you should expect is that Haeck was writing in 2007, before Delphi strings became Unicode and the RTL did any automatic code-page conversions. You're using Delphi XE, where `string` is `UnicodeString`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your knowledgeable comments! I agree with your statement `Unless you're dealing with text, don't use TStringStream, string, or AnsiString.` However, the other procedure in the edited OP succeeds in using an AnsiString variable to hold the decoded data. I cannot understand why that works. Could you help to comment?

Comment: Thank you for your further comments! Could you help to comment about that even with `Delphi XE`: (1) in the first procedure `QuestionOfString_StringStream`, the `ss_loaded_2.SaveToFile` saves the original information, indicating `TStringStream` hold decoded non-textual data correctly internally? (2) the `DecString` in the second procedure `QuestionOfString_NativeXML` in the edited OP holds the decoded data correctly, indicating `AnsiString` can hold decoded non-texual data intact? (3) then why cann't I use an `AnsiString` variable to get the data out of a `TStringStream` instance?

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't be using strings for this because you'll have to fight against text encodings. Instead of fixating on using strings you should use binary storage, e.g. `TBytes` and move on.

Comment: As of Delphi 2009, the only correct return type for `DecodeBase64` is `RawByteString`, so encoding won't interfere. The return type of `EncodeBase64` can be any `AnsiString` type; it doesn't really matter since Base64 consists entirely of ASCII characters, so again, code pages don't interfere. That explains why the XML code works. The stream code works when you don't actually store anything in a string variable probably because the stream keeps track of its real byte size; it's a descendant of `TBytesStream`, after all, so it might even store its data in a `TBytes` array.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you very much for your sugggestion! When I tried to use bytes as data buffer, it seems that the bytes extracted in a classic `TMemoryStream.Read` way is different from the `TStringStream.Bytes` property, as shown in the edited OP. Could you help to comment?

Comment: Hard to comment on something so nebulous.

Comment: @David Hefffernan: Thank you for your time and sorry for being nebulous. I should improve my English and logic.

Answer (score 3):

You are not taking into account that `TStringStream` derives from `TMemoryStream` and `TByteStream` in D2009+ but derived directly from `TStream` in earlier versions.  `TMemoryStream` allocates memory differently than your code is expecting, and the `TByteStream.Bytes` property represents the entire memory block that `TMemoryStream` allocates, but that does not mean that the entire contents of that memory is filled in with actual data.  There is some extra padding involved that your code needs to ignore.

See my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353069) for a more detailed explanation as to why your code is failing.

Comment: Thank you for your knowledgeable comments! :)