# Why does TStringStream.Bytes differ from what one gets from 'TStream.Read'

Tags: delphi, byte, stringstream

With TStringStream, the `bytes` using its `Bytes` property differs from the `bytes` extracted using `TStream.Read`. As shown below:

1. the `bytes` extracted using `TStream.Read` represents correct data.
2. the `bytes` using its `Bytes` property contains more data. <del>(the last byte of correct `bytes` is different from that of wrong `bytes`)</del>

Could you help to comment about the possible reason? Thank you very much for your help!

PS: Delphi XE, Windows 7. (It seems TStringStream back in Delphi 7 doesn't have LoadFromFile or SaveToFile.)

PS: The sample files can be download from SkyDrive: [REF_EncodedSample & REF_DecodedSample](http://sdrv.ms/LzLxlZ). (Zlib-compressed image file.).

```
procedure CompareBytes_2;
var
  ss_1: TStringStream;
  ss_2: TStringStream;
  sbytes_Read: TBytes;
  sbytes_Property: TBytes;
  len_sbytes_Read: Integer;
  len_sbytes_Property: Integer;
  filename: string;
begin
  filename := 'REF_EncodedSample';  // textual data
//  filename := 'REF_DecodedSample';  // non-textual data

  ss_1 := TStringStream.Create;
  ss_1.LoadFromFile(filename);
  ss_2 := TStringStream.Create;
  ss_2.LoadFromFile(filename);

  ss_1.SaveToFile(filename+ '_CopyByStringStream_1');
  ss_2.SaveToFile(filename+ '_CopyByStringStream_2');

  len_sbytes_Read := ss_1.Size;
  SetLength(sbytes_Read, len_sbytes_Read);
  ss_1.Read(sbytes_Read[0], len_sbytes_Read);

  sbytes_Property := ss_2.Bytes;

  ShowMessage(
    BoolToStr(
      Length(sbytes_Read) = Length(sbytes_Property),
      True));

  ShowMessage(
    BoolToStr(
      sbytes_Read[len_sbytes_Read - 1] = sbytes_Property[len_sbytes_Read - 1],
      True));

  ss_1.Free;
  ss_2.Free;
end;
```

Comment: You say that the last byte differs between the two arrays, but your code shows you comparing the *lengths* of the arrays, not their contents. Are the lengths the same? Are any of the bytes equal between the arrays? How much do the arrays differ?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Thank you for your comments! Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: No, the Lengths ARE NOT the same, because `TStringStream` will allocate more memory for its `Bytes` property than there are bytes actually stored in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string stream [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TBytesStream.Bytes) states:

> The Bytes property returns the buffer in which the data is stored. Use the Size property to find the actual amount of data in the buffer.

Presumably the buffer has been allocated to hold more space than it actually needs. Only the first Size bytes of the buffer contain valid content.

---

Also, the call to ss_1.Read is a little pointless since Length(sbytes_Read) does not change after the call to SetLength. And when reading from a stream you are to use ReadBuffer rather than Read. Likewise for WriteBuffer.

Comment: Thank you for your help very much! Could you elaborate a little bit about your last paragraph? It seems that `TStream.ReadBuffer` takes the same parameters as `TStream.Read`?

Comment: ReadBuffer raises an exception if it fails to read all the bytes. If you use Read you need to check that yourself. Read is useful if you don't to fail when you can't read all the bytes. Your code omits error checking on the call to Read, a very common error. Of course that call to Read does nothing useful anyway. That was true in your original question.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible for `Read()` to return different bytes than what is in the `Bytes` property, as `Read()` reads from the same `TBytes` object in memory that the `Bytes` property uses.

In D2009+, `TStringStream` was changed to derive from TBytesStream, which in turn derives from `TMemoryStream`.  That is why `TStringStream` has `LoadFromFile()` and `SaveToFile()` methods available now.  In earlier versions, `TStringStream` derived directly from `TStream` instead.  `TStringStream` now stores encoded bytes, not a `String` like it did in earlier versions.  The `TStringStream` contructor takes a `String` as input and encodes it to a `TBytes` using the specified `TEncoding` (where `TEncoding.Default` is used if you do not specify a `TEncoding`).  The `DataString` property getter decodes that same `TBytes` back to a `String` using the `TEncoding` that was specified in the constructor.  The `LoadFromFile()` and `SaveToFile()` methods load/save the `TBytes` as-is without any encoding/decoding performed at all.

So, if you call `LoadFromFile()`, it will store the file data as-is in the stream.  If the encoding of that data does not match the `TEncoding` that is passed to the constructor, the `DataStream` property is going to return garbage, but the `Bytes` property and the `Read()` method will work just fine.

Your problem is you are not taking into account that the `Bytes` property returns the entire memory block that `TMemoryStream` allocates for its data storage.  `TMemoryStream` allocates memory in chunks based on deltas, so it is possible for it to allocate more memory than it actually needs, that is why it has separate `Capacity` and `Size` properties.  The `Capacity` property indicates the total size of the allocated memory, whereas the `Size` property indicates how many bytes have been stored in the allocated memory.  When you call `LoadFromFile()`, the `Bytes` property will almost always be larger than the size of the file that was loaded.

So basically, your code is comparing the proverbial "apples" to "oranges", which is why you are getting bad results.  You need to fix your code accordingly, to account for the difference between the `Capacity` and `Size` properties.  The contents of the two `TBytes` variables will be identical **up to `Size` bytes**.  You are comparing more than that, which is why your code is failing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your knowledgeable comments! :) Your inside-out analysis helps a lot!